# Direction of Normal Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Can someone please explain to me why is it $N\sin(\theta) = W$ instead of $-N\sin(\theta) = W$? Isn't $N\sin(\theta)$ in the opposite direction of $W$?

[image]

Comment: Don't make us make assumptions! Your setup is vague. What is the motion of the particle? Is the vertical position of the particle constant? Is the speed constant? Is $r$ constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to such problems are based on the use of Newton's second law $\vec F = m\vec a$.
Because force and acceleration are vector quantities it is often easier to resolve there quantities into components in particular directions which is this case are up  and down, and left and right.
One direction of the two directions is then considered positive, and in this case say left and up.

Equation $(2)$ is a direct application of Newtons second law

$\text{force to the left = mass } \times \text{centripetal acceleration}$

Equation $(1)$ is an adaptation of Newton's second law used when the net acceleration in a particular direction (up in this case) is zero.

So you have $\Sigma \vec F = m \times \,0 =0$

The forces can be split up into those which are upward (positive) and those that are downward (negative).

So you then have $\Sigma (F_{\rm up} -F_{\rm down}) =0 \Rightarrow \Sigma F_{\rm up} -\Sigma F_{\rm down} =0 \Rightarrow \Sigma F_{\rm up} =\Sigma F_{\rm down}$

So using Newton's second law the route to equation $(1)$ is $N\sin \theta - W = m\,0 \Rightarrow N\sin \theta = W$

As in this case for brevity etc, the intermediate steps are omitted and $\text{force up}$ is equated to $\text{force down}$ as a result of the acceleration in that direction being zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually balancing of forces.
We are equating the magnitudes not the directions.If we consider the vertical equilibrium of the ball

$W(-\hat{ĵ}) + N\sin\theta(\hat{ĵ})=0$

$W(\hat{ĵ}) = N\sin\theta(\hat{ĵ})$

$W = N\sin\theta$

$\hat{ĵ}$ is unit vector in vertical direction

Comment: Please Don't down vote on a whim . Comment if u want more clarification 

Comment: @Muzammilahmed https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The second statement is correct and exact as force is a vector and two vectors are equal if they are equal in "magnitude and direction".

The first equation is just equating magnitudes of forces    .(this helps to solve problem without having to follow  a sign convention)

You would find the first type of equation where directions of forces on both sides of the equation are already known (at most of the times).

You use the second form when dealing with forces which have a variable direction and magnitude eg. friction between multiple blocks on top of each other,tension in complex pulley systems.

The equation of the second form can be used everywhere but it gets confusing and increases chances of error when there are multiple steps and in the end you have to rely on knowing the direction of forces.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ball is in equilibrium in Y direction , therefore net force on it must be 0.

A better way to write this is  :

If we take upward as positive and downward as negative

$N\sin(\theta)-W=0$